# How to solve BAISED on SPOJ?

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I am trying to solve this SPOJ problem http://www.spoj.com/problems/BAISED/  .

My Approach

```
for all elements in the preferred_position array
 if(position>0&&position<=n)
    if(position is unoccupied)
       allocate position for user
 else
   reach the first free position in the array

for all elements whose preferred position is already filled
    search both directions left,right to find nearest free_position
```

I tried many test cases and got them right and I don't know where i failed and getting Wrong answer. And i chose this problem based on greedy tag and i really don't know where to apply greedy technique. Can anyone please throw some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where i will be wrong? Here's a link to the code [ideone.com/O4ood1](http://ideone.com/O4ood1)

It was very painful to read your code.. and you solution is not right 100%, because:

1. there could  be very big numbers bigger than 10^10 and what are you doing wrong - it's decrease such number by one until you reach n, *your life it is too short to wait when your solution will find the result for test with such big numbers...* (***if you want a[i] became less or equal than n, why simply not to write a[i] = n***)

   ```
   while(t2>n)
       {
           t2--;
           cnt1++;
       }
   ```
2. I ran your code on the same test case two times, but in the second
   run I change the order of given numbers in test and your solution shows
   different answers:

   *I delete reading the strings for easier debugging.. so I provide test without names of teams*

   ***First run on test:***

   1

   10

   2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 7 6

   And your solution shows that result is **6** ( *what is wrong
   answer*)

   ***Second run:*** Lets change swap last two numbers and get

   `2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 6 7`

   And your solution shows that answer is ***8*** (Fortunately it is
   right answer)
3. Suppose there are two unplaced numbers ***a[6] = 6*** and ***a[9] = 9***, 
   and 
   there are two free places ***1 and 8***,

   your solution will take **6**   go **two** steps right and will put **6** in position **8**, then will take **9** and put in position **1**.

   If you draw lines from **start** position of your number to its
   **destination** you will see that line from **9** to **1** fully **cover** line from **6** to **8**... Looks like not optimal.

   So you should try to avoid this **overlapping**.

   Now draw lines from **6 to 1** and from **9 to 8**, there is not
   overlapping and now it is optimal.

   ```
   So to avoid overlapping   you can for example to sort rest of your numbers.
   ```

Comment: Thanks a ton @d40a and sorry for the buggy and hard to understand code

Answer (score 2):

This is my accepted solution!!

I send it few times until recognize that numbers could be very big, so I change everything to long long

Simply sort number and then find the differents between their positions.

How I reached this solution:

> 1) you should place all teams in positions from 0 to n - 1
>
> 2) lets place as many teams as possible in their preferred places
>
> 3) rest unplaced teams have the same preferred positions as placed
>   teams  or preferred positions are large then n - 1 (or n - if
>   enumerated from 1)
>
> 4) As we remember that  we need to fell all positions from 0 to n - 1,
>   so  it is obvious that if we sort the unplaced teams we could minimize
>   the answer

Why I skip 2nd step(you can try to proof it), lets look at example test:

> ```
> 1
> 3
> first team 2
> second team 3
> third team 4
> 4 2 3 -> |1 - 4| + |2 - 2| + |3 - 3| = 3
> 2 3 4 -> |1 - 2| + |2 - 3| + |3 - 4| = 3
> ```

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>

    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
        long long t;
        cin >> t;
        vector <long long> a;
        for (long long i = 0; i < t; i++) {
           long long n;
           cin >> n;
            a.clear();
            for (long long j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                string s;
                cin >> s;
                long long p ;
                cin >> p;
                p--;
                a.push_back(p);
            }
            sort(a.begin(), a.end());
            long long ans = 0;
            for (long long i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {

                ans += abs(a[i] - i);
            }
            cout << ans << '\n';
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand how this leads to the optimal solution as a change in position_preferred and position_allotted may cause the change in the successive elements. I positioned elements whose preferred positions is within the range and if the position is empty first. Later I traversed both left and right to get nearest place for the elements whose preferred position is already occupied. Where i will be wrong? Here's a link to the code http://ideone.com/O4ood1

Comment: @user I know test case on which your solution will fall. I will try to formalize and explain.